# Porting my Website from Windows Apache Server to Linux Apache server, and Warnings appear

Tags: php, linux, windows, apache2

i'm porting a web site from windows to a linux machine. the same sourcode was working fine on the windows machine, but once on linux(Debian) some pages show me some errors, i updated both php version to the latest, enabled errors E_ALL on windows but, still the same!

Here are the errors, on two different pages.

1

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /var/www/ticcity/smsapp/header.php:78) in
>   /var/www/ticcity/smsapp/header.php on line 103

2

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at /var/www/ticcity/smsapp/envoi.php:2)
>   in /var/www/ticcity/smsapp/header.php on line 2

Answer (score 0):

you try to echo a response to the client twice. 
this might happen in the following php code:

```
echo 'return result';
exit;
return 'hello';
```

Comment: also might happen if you try to do a session_start after a session was already closed.

Comment: but what if close a session and want to reopen it ?  i thought that the problem is to open a session when a previous session was already opened. but why i don't get any errors on windows side? even though i was getting some errors when i did something wrong.

Comment: you can echo a few times and only when your done do the return. just dont return response to the browser too early. because after you return you are done. until the browser will call you again and a new session will start :)

Comment: uhm, i don't really understand what you mean :s

Comment: you should close the session / return a result to the browser on the last line. just like a function cant return a value and still do stuff after it.